# C# FormのTransparencyKeyの透明設定の挙動について

Tags: c#, form

お世話になります。

以前もTransparencyKeyによるフォームの透過について質問したのですが、まだ解決しないので
もう一度質問させていただきます。

FormにTransparencyKeyを設定して、フォーム部分の透過処理をさせると、透明になった部分(TransparencyKeyの該当する色の部分)は、フォームをすり抜けて、背面にマウスイベントが
走り、あたかも切り抜いた形にフォームができているような操作ができたと思います。いろいろな
サイトを見ていますが、確かにそうなっていました。下記のサイト様もそうですが。

http://hima-tubusi.blogspot.com/2016/11/c.html

ですが、最近同じことをすると、見た目では確かに透過しているものの、透過部分をすり抜けて
背面の操作をすることはできません。飽く迄フォームの矩形のまま、マウスイベントが発生して
います。

これはいつからこういう仕様になってしまったのでしょうか。不具合ではなく、正式な仕様だと
するならば、今後はずっとこの仕様のままなのでしょうか？

個人的には、以前のほうがおもしろいことができたので気に入っていたのですが、少し残念です。

詳細をご存じの方がおりましたら、お教えいただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `Form.Opacity`を使われていますでしょうか？

Comment: 検索すると古いのも多いですがこの辺に何かありそうです。[Transparencykey OSの違い?](http://bbs.wankuma.com/index.cgi?mode=al2&namber=80483&KLOG=137), [フォームウィンドウの特定の色を透明にする](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/form/transparencykey.html), [Click-through form on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33509542/9014308), [C# Form.TransparencyKey working different for different colors, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448771/c-sharp-form-transparencykey-working-different-for-different-colors-why), [Transparent Windows Form that can handle Click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32783183/9014308)

Comment: Win10Pro,VSC2019で紹介記事を試したら、`BackColor`がデフォルトの`Control`ではマウスが透過出来て、R:赤とB:青の値が違う`ActiveCaption`では透過しませんでした。英語版記事のようにバグと色設定の組み合わせが原因かもしれません。

Comment: sayuriさん、Opacityは使用していません。

Answer (score 1):

kunif さんの コメントのリンクからたどっていった先のリンクに ズバリの回答がありました。

透過の色を

```
this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
```

や

```
this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Fuchsia;
```

にすると 希望通りに背景の色を透過してマウスクリックできるようになります。

色によっては マウスイベントが透過しないようです。

※ 上記2つの色は透過できるのを確認しました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448771/c-sharp-form-transparencykey-working-different-for-different-colors-why

また Windows の Aero の機能を ON にしたり OFF にすることでこの動作も変わってくるそうです。

Comment: 以前はできて最近できなくなった、という質問に答えられていないように思います。また現行OSでAero機能をOFFにできましたっけ？

Comment: 半透明つながりで何かしら関係あるかも。ON/OFFも出来なくは無いようです。Win10系[Windows 10の「Aero」と「仮想デスクトップ 」の使い方](https://www.pc-koubou.jp/magazine/292), [AeroGlass記事](https://www.japan-secure.com/entry/how_to_prioritize_the_performance_of_windows_10_1.html#Aero-Glass), [AeroSnap記事](https://pc-karuma.net/windows-10-disable-aero-snap/), [AeroShake記事](https://qiita.com/kawaidainfinity/items/17ff4527d8bf8ca4b879), Win7 [Windows 7 Aero 「エアロ」機能を「無効」「有効」にする](https://www.pasoble.jp/windows/7/08812.html)

Comment: まだ、ちゃんとした確認ができていないので 回答には記入できなかったのですが、リンク先の記載では Aero が有効な場合は デスクトップウィンドウの合成機能が使われ、Aero 無効な場合は ビデオアダプターの オーバーレイ機能が使われる。 となっており、なんだか逆な気がして・・。DWM について詳しく調べてから追記しようと思ったのですが・・。 Windows 10は DWM が 既定で 無効となっており、レジストリで設定変更可能？ ちょっと情報が整理できていません。

Comment: 皆さんありがとうございます。たった今確認しました。遅れましてすみません。結局のところ、やはり『不具合』であって、今のところは正しく動作する色を選ぶしかないということなのでしょうか？

Comment: 本日、再度確認しましたが、やはり『選択する色によって』できたりできなかったりのようです。これを踏まえれば、不具合だということも納得がいきます。ただ、だいぶ以前から出ている不具合のようですので、改善される可能性はかなり低いのかもしれません。今のところ、『できる色』を使用して組んでいくしかなさそうです。

Comment: プログラムを開発していると時々ある「最初の計画だとこれは不具合なんだけど・・この仕様を変えると影響が大きすぎるよね・・・これはこれで仕様という事で、いいかな・・」という会話が MS の中であるのか、無いのか・・。